# Calculating a radioactive sample's mass from its activity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, radioactivity

The question reads as such: "What is the mass of a 1.05 µCi carbon-14 source?"

First I convert to decays/s: $R = 1.05 µCi=3.885 \times 10^4 decays/s$.

The half-life for carbon-14 that we've been using is 5730 years or $T_{1/2}=1.808 \times 10^{11} s$, so $\lambda=\frac{ln(2)}{T_{1/2}}=3.834 \times 10^{-12}s^{-1}$

$R=\lambda N$, so $N=\frac{R}{\lambda}=1.0133 \times 10^{16}nuclei$

Now just to convert to grams: $1.0133 \times 10^{16}nuclei \times \frac{1mol}{N_A} \times \frac{12.011g}{1mol}=2.02 \times 10^{-7}g$. Which unfortunately is the wrong answer. Maybe someone sees a conversion error I made somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon 14 has a mass of 14, not 12.